# Convert string to date and compare two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I get a date in a variable in string format in javascript. It is like `26-02-2015`.

Then I get today's date in another variable using `new Date()`. This gives me a long string like `Mon Feb 23 2015 10:56:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

How can I compare these two date? I want to check which date is bigger.

This is what I am doing

```
var date = objParam[0].value;
var todaysDate = new Date();

if (date > todaysDate)
    alert("Please select the valid date");
```

Comment: what exactly you want to compare ? explain little more.

Comment: I want to check which date is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
date = new Date();
dateNew = (date.getDate()).toString() + "-" + 
          (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" +
          (date.getFullYear()).toString();
```

**`dateNew`** contains the string with the format you mentioned. Now you can compare the two strings.

Comment: @Lokesh is it so hard to comment or choose an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d1='26-02-2015';
d1=d1.split('-');
var parsedDate=d1[1]+'/'+d1[0]+'/'+d1[2];
if(Date.now() > new Date(parsedDate).getTime()){
  
     alert('past date')
  } else {
    
       alert('future date');
    }
```